# Groovy Spock Unit test throwing NullPointerException because mock object is null

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I am writing some tests for a class which processing orders and sets the completed orders to be ready for shipping. The orders are retrieved for a customer and the order status for completed orders is used to complete the processing.  However, when I run my tests, they fail saying 
'Cannot get completedLines on a null object...' From the error, it is clear that the OrderStatus object is null. However, I set it up when creating the test as shown

```
ordersService.getStatus(orders) >> orderStatus

   OrdersService ordersService
   DiscountService discountService
   ShippingService shippingService


  Order getCustomerOrder(Long customerId) {
    List<Order> orders = 
          ordersService.retrieveOrderWithDiscount(customerId);
    List<LoyaltyDiscount> discounts = 
        discountService.getDiscounts(customerId,orders);
    OrderStatus orderStatus = ordersService.getStatus(orders);

  shippingService.processCompletedOrders(orderStatus.completedLines,orders);

    }



 class OrderSpecification extends Specification {
    OrdersService ordersService
    DiscountService discountService
    ShippingService shippingService

   def setup(){
     ordersService = Mock(OrdersService)
     discountService=  Mock(DiscountService)
     shippingService = Mock(ShippingService)
   }

   def 'completed orders with discounts should be shipped' (){
      given:
        long id =12334
        List <Order> orders = .. createOrders()
        OrderStatus orderStatus = createOrderStatus()
        ordersService.retrieveOrderWithDiscount(12345) >> orders
        ordersService.getStatus(orders) >> orderStatus
        shippingService.processCompletedOrders(orderStatus.completedLines,orders)
     ... rest omitted
   }

 }
```

Comment: Your sample code is not very helpful, I am afraid. You cut out information, other lines of code are redundant. The initialisation is `orderStatus = createOrderStatus()`, but what does `createOrderStatus()` do? Obviously it returns `null`, as far as I can tell from the scarce information you provide. Information hiding does not get anyone closer to an answer. Please edit your question and turn it into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then notify us with a comment. You are a developer, so you should know how to make a problem reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this test was not failing, another was.